# How to prevent Xamarin.Forms app from navigating to pages with no internet connection?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using the Xam.Plugin.Connectivity plugin to detect if there is an internet connection within my app.  I had no problems implementing internet detection error handling with the plugin, but when I click on a button to navigate to another page when there is no internet connection, the app just crashes.  Here's some example code:

```
     private async void Current_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.IsConnected)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "Connection to the internet has been lost.", "ok");
        }
    }

   async void OnClickSomePage()
   {
     //Go to some page
   }
```

What do I do to prevent the app from going to the next page if there's no internet connection?

Comment: please post the code that is causing the crash

Answer (score 0):

Before you navigate to any page, you should check if internet is available or not by following code:

```
if(CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected) 
{  
    //Navigate here
}
else
{
    //Show some alert, No internet connectivity.
}
```

More details [here](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/CheckingConnectivity.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
async void OnClickSomePage()
{
    if(CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
    {
         //Navigate
    }
    else
    {
        // Display a message
        await DisplayAlert("No internet", "", "Ok");
    }
}
```